# Erro no PHPmailer: Configuração pela Hostnet

Tags: php, phpmailer

segue o codigo utilizado retirado da ultima versão do gitHub que encontrei

```
    <?php

// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load composer's autoloader
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';
require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                             
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                               
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.dominiodahostnet.com.br';              
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                              
    $mail->Username = 'usuario=dominiodahostnet.com.br';                 
    // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '****';                                   
    //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                          
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@dominiodahostnet.com.br', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('address@dominiodahostnet.com.br', 'Joe User');   
    //$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               l
    //$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         
    //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    
    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                 
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Abaixo o erro gerado

```
2017-09-20 17:58:23 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtpq.f1.k8.com.br ESMTP Postfix
2017-09-20 17:58:23 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.dominiodahostnet.com.br
2017-09-20 17:58:23 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtpq.f1.k8.com.br250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 33554432250-ETRN250-STARTTLS250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-8BITMIME250 DSN
2017-09-20 17:58:23 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2017-09-20 17:58:23 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2017-09-20 17:58:23 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2017-09-20 17:58:23 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2017-09-20 17:58:23 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: 
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

Avisando que estou realizando os testes diretamente do servidor e não pelo localhost

Comment: Não seria $mail->Username = 'dominiodahostnet.com.br'; ao inves de $mail->Username = '`usuario`=dominiodahostnet.com.br';

Comment: Não, o Usarname do servidor da hostnet e deste jeito mesmo

Comment: ok, mais um conhecimento adquirido

Answer (score 4):

A porta `587` geralmente é uma porta que usa SSL ou TLS, então você deve descomentar o `$mail->SMTPSecure` e primeiro teste `tls`:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

Se não der certo teste `ssl`:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```

Se a mensagem de erro **ainda for**:

> Could not connect to SMTP host.

É porque provavelmente a extensão para conexões segura esta comentada no php.ini:

Se for Windows Server:

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Se for Linux/Unix:

```
;extension=openssl.so
```

Remova o `;` e reinicie o Apache ou Ngnix, se você não tiver controle sobre o servidor e o php.ini só entrando em contato com o suporte deles.

### Se o intuito é não usar encriptação TLS/SSL

Para desabilitar o `STARTTLS` e/ou a conexão segura ajuste o PHPMailer assim:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
```

---

### Nota extra

Essa linha parece errada:

```
$mail->Username = 'usuario=dominiodahostnet.com.br';
```

Creio que o correto seja:

```
$mail->Username = 'usuario@dominiodahostnet.com.br';
```

Ou sem o domínio:

```
$mail->Username = 'usuario';
```

Comment: o servidor não utiliza segurança de conexão, nem a tls ou a ssl.
Descomentando a linha $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; a mensagem de erro dar a mesma, e quando substituir para ssl deu a seguinte:


2017-09-20 18:51:51 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Message could not be sent. Mensagem de Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Sobre o Username e a mesma coisa, o servidor manda eu colocar desse modo usando o = ao invés do @.

Comment: @JulianoSilveira tenta isso `$mail->SMTPSecure = false;
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;`

Comment: fiz a alteração para deixar o TLS falso, mas agora acontece um erro quando o servidor tenta enviar a mensagem para o remetente dando o seguinte problema SERVER -> CLIENT: 554 5.7.1 <unknown[179.223.237.28]>: Client host rejected: Access denied.
vou atualizar a pergunta para esse novo problema

Comment: @JulianoSilveira Access denied provavelmente é o UserName ou senha que estão errados.

Comment: Pior que estar parecendo que sim, estou alterando o  UserName e a senha para ver o que acontece e a mensagem não se alterá

Comment: @JulianoSilveira tenta alterar o formato do UserName usando o `@` ao invés de `=` e se não der certo tente remover tudo depois do `=`, ou seja usando somente assim `$mail->Username = 'usuario';`, se nenhum dos 2 der certo me manda o nome da hospedagem que você usa pra eu procurar a documentação e tentar te ajudar.

Comment: não sei se influencia mais o ip resultante do cliente desconhecido [<unknown[179.223.237.28]>] não possui conexão smtp

Comment: @JulianoSilveira esta usando https://www.hostnet.com.br/ ? Se sim acessa isto https://www.hostnet.com.br/config.email/ gera o manual e me manda ele "gerado" pra eu tentar configurar o phpmailer pra ti.

Comment: Obrigado @JulianoSilveira consegui fazer funcionar seguindo esse tutorial https://www.hostnet.com.br/info/funcao-mail-do-php/#Configurando

Comment: A Hostnet precisa liberá o envio de e-mail pelo painel. por isso a senha e UserName não funcionava, por que devia ser puxado da configuração gerada pelo painel e não pelo PHPMailer

Comment: Obrigado, Guilherme Nascimento pela sua dica.

Há semanas que eu estou procurando uma solução para esse erro de envio de e-mail pelo servidor da Hostnet. Depois que o PHPMailer foi atualizado para a versão 6.0.1, não consegui mais enviar e-mail pelo formulário do meu site. Depois de muito procurar uma resposta pela internet, encontrei a sua dica neste site (stackoverflow). Assim que eu adicionei ao meu código PHP, resolveu o problema!

Answer (score 0):

Para quem encontrar o mesmo problema que eu.

Arquivo php:

```
    <?php

    // Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
    // These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    //Load composer's autoloader
    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                             
    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                               
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.dominiodahostnet.com.br';              
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                              
        $mail->Username = 'usuario=dominiodahostnet.com.br';                 
        // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = '****';                                   
        //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                          
        $mail->Port = 587;                                    

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('from@dominiodahostnet.com.br', 'Mailer');
        $mail->addAddress('address@dominiodahostnet.com.br', 'Joe User');   
        //$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               l
        //$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
        //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
        //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

        //Attachments
        //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         
        //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    
        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                 
        $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
        $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

        $mail->send();
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
```

Arquivo .user.ini

```
        authmail.debug = Off
         authmail.port = 587
         authmail.address = "exemplo@seudominio.com"
         authmail.smtp_account = "exemplo=seudominio.com"
         authmail.smtp = "smtp.seudominio.com"
         authmail.password = "Aqui-você-coloca-a-senha-do-seu-e-mail"
```

o arquivo .user.ini deverá ser gerado no painel da hostnet copiado e colado em um bloco de nota.

concluído isso basta jogar via ftp na hospedagem e testar